# Group by not working after upgrading to laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

This is the code that was working on laravel 5.2

```
$menus = CmsMenuItem::groupBy('menu_id')->get();
```

but now it throws error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1
>   of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
>   column 'convertifier_cms.cms_menu_items.id' which is not functionally
>   dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from 'cms_menu_items' group
>   by 'menu_id')

I have also tried

```
 `strict => false`
```

in database.php but no effect

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this for database config.

```
 'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

and use query like this way

```
$menus =DB::table('cms_menu_item')
    ->select('*')
    ->groupBy('menu_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: ```php artisan config:clear``` after config changes

Comment: how to do it in Lumen 8? any suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

As per this PR just try this in your database config

```
'strict' => false,
```

If not there is some known issue is going on.

Please refer these links [PR](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/3905) & [Issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14997)

Answer (score 5):

Go to your config/database.php folder. In mysql configuration array, change strict => true to strict => false, and everything will work nicely.

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```